# How to create function, returning pointer to another function without typedef in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

For example I have following functions:

```
char ret_a(int x)
{
    return 'a'+x;
}

typedef char (*fptr)(int);

fptr hyperfunc(float a, int b)
{
    return &ret_a;
}
```

How can I get rid of typedef?

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of them like this. Third function returns pointer to function which returns pointer to function which retruns char.

```
char ret_a(int x)
{
    return 'a'+x;
}

char (*hyperfunc(float a, int b))(int)
{
    char (*fp)(int) = &ret_a;
    return fp;
}

char (*(*superhyper(double a))(float, int))(int)
{
    char (*(*fpp)(float, int))(int)=&hyperfunc;
    return fpp;
}
```